# Pandas dataframe row-wise formula with function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, vectorization

So I have quite big DataFrame and I create a new column by some equation based on other columns:

```
df['F'] = (params.a * params.b * df.A/1000 - param.C * (df.B + df.C - df.D) + param.D * df.E
```

and it works perfectly fine. Except I want to **repeat this function throughout the code**, so instead of error-prone copying and pasting I want to cast it into a reusable function.

So I casted it into lambda:

```
def fun(r):
     return (params.a * params.b * r.A/1000 - param.C * (r.B + r.C - r.D) + param.D * r.E   
df['F'] = r.apply(funy,axis =1)
```

yet this is 5x *slower* now (**1.2s vs 6s** for 10k rows).

What should I do if I want to have a neat function and still benefit from speed?

Comment: Second one is not recommendable. first one is vectorized approach.

Comment: Try lambda inside apply function

Comment: @AniketDixit but this means repeating the code everytime I use it, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
def fun():
    return params.a * params.b * df.A/1000 - param.C * (df.B + df.C - df.D) + param.D * df.E

df['F'] = fun()
```

So you get a reusable vectorized function.

Comment: nice shortcut, let me try it.

Comment: works like charm, %timeit gives exactly the same computation times. Only limitation (not for my case) is that it has to be in the same namespace and using variables that are already there. So best way is to define it inside a function from which you call